# Bind property between sibling user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have the below problem: I have two different user controls inside a parent user control. These are `trainList`, which holds a list of train objects and `trainView`, which is an user control that shows details of the selected train in the list.

My wish is to share a variable of `trainList` with `trainView`.
What I have now is:

*Parent user control:*

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl>
        <customControls:trainList x:Name="trainList"></customControls:trainList>
    </UserControl>

    <UserControl>
        <customControls:trainView x:Name="trainView"></customControls:trainView>
    </UserControl>

    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=trainList, Path=SelectedTrain}" Text="{ Binding SelectedTrain.Id }">Test text</TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

*TrainList class:*

```
public partial class TrainList : UserControl
    {
        public TrainList()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public Train SelectedTrain { get; set; }

        public void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print(this.SelectedTrain.Id);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** The Train class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If I got this to work, I'd apply the binding to the `trainView` user control (not sure if this would work) instead to the text block.

```
    <UserControl>
        <customControls:trainView x:Name="trainView" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=trainList, Path=SelectedTrain}"></customControls:trainView>
    </UserControl>
```

And then, I would access that variable someway from the code-behind of `trainView`.

(And after this, I would like to share a different variable from `trainView` with its parent user control, but maybe that's another question).

My current question is: could this be done this way or would I need to follow another strategy?

Comment: First, you should under no circumstance have `DataContext = this;` in the constructor of a UserControl, as it breaks any typical DataContext based Bindings of its dependency properties. Second, the two user controls should share a comman view model, which may be provided by the outer UserControl. The properties of both TrainList and TrainView (or its comontents) would be bound to the common view model, which would hold the SelectedTrain property and another property with alist of all trains.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your answer. I'm new to WPF and never applied MVVM pattern. I don't know if it'd be too much to give me an example implementation of the common view model you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this simple view model, with a base class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and a Train, TrainViewModel and MainViewModel class.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(
        ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(storage, value))
        {
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}

public class Train : ViewModelBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { SetValue(ref name, value); }
    }

    private string details;
    public string Details
    {
        get { return details; }
        set { SetValue(ref details, value); }
    }

    // more properties
}

public class TrainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Train> Trains { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Train>();

    private Train selectedTrain;
    public Train SelectedTrain
    {
        get { return selectedTrain; }
        set { SetValue(ref selectedTrain, value); }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public TrainViewModel TrainViewModel { get; } = new TrainViewModel();
}
```

which may be initialized in the MainWindow's constructor like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;

    vm.TrainViewModel.Trains.Add(new Train
    {
        Name = "Train 1",
        Details = "Details of Train 1"
    });

    vm.TrainViewModel.Trains.Add(new Train
    {
        Name = "Train 2",
        Details = "Details of Train 2"
    });
}
```

The TrainDetails controls would look like this, of course with more elements for more properties of the Train class:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and the parent UserControl like this, where I directly use a ListBox instead of a TrainList control:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Trains}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrain}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <local:TrainDetailsControl Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedTrain}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It would be instantiated in the MainWindow like this:

```
<Grid>
    <local:TrainControl DataContext="{Binding TrainViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that in this simple example the elements in the UserControls' XAML bind directly to a view model instance that is passed via their DataContext. This means that the UserControl know the view model (or at least their properties). A more general approach is to declare dependency properties in the UserControl class, that are bound to view model properties. The UserControl would then be independent of any particular view model.

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful. But, if I wanted to use another UserControl instead of directly a ListBox, what should I put? I have tried with `<local:TrainListControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>` but the list doesn't get filled, is blank (the TrainsDetailsControl works well when I use ListBox directly).

Comment: Oh, ok. I overthought this. Just `<local:TrainListControl />` works well.